# Images on wordpress arent loading

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress, content-security-policy

I've recently installed a clean wordpress installation on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server using nginx. Now i'm running into an error, when I've uploaded my images, I cant see them on the page.

Thats what the network console is giving me in my browser:

Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  ".

I dont know how to fix this, so I would appreciate if anyone knows how to fix this :)

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you have a CSP plug-in for your WordPress site, or are you setting the headers in your Nginx configuration?

Comment: Is your WordPress site using HTTPS? Do you have a valid certificate? Are the `img` tags referencing https? It looks like not everything is consistently & properly using HTTPS across your WordPress/nginx setup

Comment: @RichardSmith No, I don't have a CSP plugin for my WordPress Site. This is my Nginx config file:

user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf-enabled/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}

(note) I've installed iRedmail before, and it apperantly changed the config files by it self.

Comment: @AMtwo Yes it is using HTTPS signed by a letsencrypt certificate.

Comment: Did you reset the browser before testing. If this is the same website I looked at earlier, it seems to be loading on `https` fine.

Comment: Yup, I did. They're kinda working. I tried to import some demo data from a wordpress theme. Now my Media Library looks like this: 

https://i.imgur.com/YKPba2Z.png

I can also post images in a post - even if theyre blank in the media library, but somehow they arent shown on the front page.

https://clan.addictedtogames.de/?p=4718